# Doesn't process the loop

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and  trying to create a simple application where I have it set to read lines from the text file. The first line is the question and second line is answer. Now, I am able to read the question and answer. But the part where I compare user answer with the actual answer, it doesn't perform the actions in the loop even when the answer entered is correct.
My code :

```
def populate():

print("**************************************************************************************************************")
f=open("d:\\q.txt")
questionList=[]

b = 1
score=0
start=0

for line in f.read().split("\n"):
    questionList.append(line)


while b<len(questionList):
    a = questionList[start]
    print(a)
    userinput=input("input user")
    answer=questionList[b]
    b = b + 2
    print(answer)
    if userinput==answer:
        score =score+1
        print(score)
    else:
        break
    start += 2
```

I would really appreciate any guidance on this. 
My q.txt file:

```
1. Set of instructions that you write to tell a computer what to do.
Program
2. A language's set of rules.
Syntax
3. Describes the programs that operate the computer.
System Software
4.To achieve a working program that accomplishes its intended tasks by removing all syntax and logical errors from the program
Debugging
5.a program that creates and names computer memory locations and can hold values, and write a series of steps or operations to manipulate those values
Procedural Program
6. The named computer memory locations.
Variables
7. The style of typing the first initial of an identifier in lowercase and making the initial of the second word uppercase. -- example -- "payRate"
Camel Casing
8. Individual operations within a computer program that are often grouped together into logical units.
Methods
9. This is an extension of procedural programming in terms of using variables and methods, but it focuses more on objects.
Object Oriented Programming
10. A concrete entity that has behaviors and attributes.
Objects
```

Comment: What format is your file in?

Comment: Check for things like additional whitespace around the user inputs and answer.  Use `.strip()` if you think it's appropriate.  For debugging purposes, print out all variables on each loop, or use pdb for more interactive debugging.

Comment: @rassar my file is in .txt format .

Comment: Fix the formatting in your question above. Also, try printing `repr(userinput)` and `repr(answer)` to make sure there's not a stray newline or space messing with you.

Comment: You never update `start` in your loop. There are more pythonic ways to do this. Could you give an example of your questions file.

Comment: @Harvey I have updated my question with the file.

Comment: Off-topic: `print("*-repeated-a-hundred-times")` -> `print("*" * 100)`.

Comment: Solved!!! Thank you guys. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was:

- always asking the same question: `questionList[start]`
- throwing away the value of `every`
- replacing every space in answers with nothing, so "System Software" becomes "SystemSoftware"
- failing to factor in case: need to use `.lower()` on `userinput` and `answer`.

Here's a more pythonic implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from itertools import islice


# Read in every line and then put alternating lines together in
# a list like this [ (q, a), (q, a), ... ]
def get_questions(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
    number_of_lines = len(lines)
    if number_of_lines == 0:
        raise ValueError('No questions in {}'.format(filename))
    if number_of_lines % 2 != 0:
        raise ValueError('Missing answer for last question in {}'.filename)
    return list(zip(islice(lines, 0, None, 2), islice(lines, 1, None, 2)))


def quiz(questions):
    score = 0
    for question, answer in questions:
        user_answer = input('\n{}\n> '.format(question))
        if user_answer.lower() == answer.lower():
            print('Correct')
            score += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect: {}'.format(answer))
    return score


questions = get_questions('questions.txt')
score = quiz(questions)
num_questions = len(questions)
print('You scored {}/{}'.format(score, num_questions))
```

Comment: Man this is awesome. Thank you.